# Memory Leak in CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am in the process of converting the available SKP_SMTP library to implement an SMTP client in my iPhone app. After a long and troubled work of bug fixing and memory checks, I have narrowed down the problems to only one. It happens that a memory leaks occurs in the call to **CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost** (evidentiated by the Leaks tool in Instruments), which seems strange to me as the *CFReadStreamRef* parameters **readStream** and **writeStream** are either **CFReleased** at a later stage, or assigned to a correspondent NSStream object via **__bridge_transfer** (and that should eventually bring the streams memory management from CoreFoundation to ARC).
I've googled around but the only solutions I have found are under garbage collection(clearly not available in ARC): am I missing something or that should not happen?
Code following,
thanks a lot

```
@implementation NSStream (SKPSMTPExtensions)

+ (void)getStreamsToHostNamed:(NSString *)hostName port:(NSInteger)port inputStream:  (NSInputStream **)inputStream outputStream:(NSOutputStream **)outputStream
{
    CFHostRef           host;
    CFReadStreamRef     readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef    writeStream;

    readStream = NULL;
    writeStream = NULL;

    host = CFHostCreateWithName(NULL, (__bridge_retained CFStringRef) hostName);
    if (host != NULL) 
    {
        // Memory leak at this line: strange as readStream & writeStream are either   CFReleased or _bridge_transfered to ARC 
        (void) CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(NULL, host, port, &readStream,   &writeStream);
        CFRelease(host);
    }

    if (inputStream == NULL) 
    {
        CFRelease(readStream);
    } 
    else 
    {
        *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *) readStream;
    }
    if (outputStream == NULL) 
    {
        CFRelease(writeStream);
    } 
    else 
    {
        *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *) writeStream;
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this statement leaks `hostName`:

```
host = CFHostCreateWithName(NULL, (__bridge_retained CFStringRef) hostName);
```

You should use a `__bridge` cast, not a `__bridge_retained` cast.

Comment: how to notice your answer a few years later :)..thanks rob